# Does a flash xmlsocket connection host need dedicated ip?

Tags: flash, xmlsocket

I want to prepare a host for my xmlsocket flash based game but i don't have any experience in this case.
do i need dedicated ip or i can run xml socket with shared ip address?

Comment: I would try it and find out. My guess is no. The days of having to use a dedicated IP for servers/services are long gone :) If you have tried it, please share your results.

Answer (score 0):

No you shouldnt need a dedicated ip address. Everything should work on your current address

Comment: Did you establish a xmlsocket connection in a host with shared ip?   if yes, what do i need for this connection ?(like: ssh access, open ports , ...)

Answer (score 0):

Everything should work on your IP but make sure its a static one

Answer (score 0):

You can use an actual URL for that instead of IP.

Comment: did  you ever worked with xml socket? experienced the suffer ?